# Simplify/expand $\ln \left(\sum^n_{i=1}x_i^{\theta-1}\right)$

Tags: summation, logarithms

Can someone help simplify/expand this natural log? I want to bring the $\theta - 1$ down in front of the $\ln$ but I don't know how the rules work with the summation.

$$\ln\left( \sum^n_{i=1}x_i^{\theta-1} \right)$$

Comment: Each xi is a separate term, so its not possible to factor out the theta-1, unless there is some relationship between the xi's.  Where did you get this example from ?

Comment: There's not much you can do, without further information. The $\theta-1$ won't come down in front, because the entire sum would need to be raised to the $\theta-1$, instead of the individual summands (unless we know something about the $x_i$ that hasn't been specified yet)

Comment: $(\theta-1)\ln\left( (\sum^n_{i=1}x_i^{\theta-1})^{1/(\theta-1)} \right)$